# What does jersey service return if @Produces annotation missing?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, restful-architecture

I was begun learn jersey for development restful web services.

As I noticed in most of the examples uses following annotations:

```
@Consumes
```

defines format of input parameters

```
@Produces
```

defines format of output parameters

But in real code I see method which looks like this:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Path("/login")
public Response login(@FormParam("login") final String username, @FormParam("password") final String password){...}
```

I see that this method uses `POST` HTTP method. Parameters `userName` and `password` will have form according   `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)`. and I see URL to execute this method.

But I don't understand what this method returns. Which format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Default Jersey produces "application/octet-stream" if it's not specified. See [this](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html) for details. It returns Response object, which contains http status that you wish to reply client to.

Comment: The correct url is now https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html
"If the request does not contain a Content-Type header then use application/octet-stream media type."

Answer (score 7):

I just want to clarify that *"By Default Jersey produces "application/octet-stream" if it's not specified"* is not entirely true. There's actually a lot of complexity going on behind the scenes, that determines the final `Content-Type`. As stated in the spec:

> Note that the above (actually *below* :-) renders a response with a default media type of `application/octetstream` **when a concrete type cannot be determined**.

But, like I said, there is a complex algorithm that goes into determining this "concrete type". And not many cases I've tested will return `application/octet-stream`. It goes as follows (this is directly from spec. You can try and make head or tails of it, but it's not for the layperson):

> ### 3.8 Determining the MediaType of Responses
>
> In many cases it is not possible to statically determine the media type of a response. The following algorithm is used to determine the response media type, M<sub>selected</sub>, at run time:
>
> 1. If the method returns an instance of `Response` whose metadata includes the response media type
>      (*M*<sub>specified</sub>) then set *M*<sub>selected</sub> = *M*<sub>specified</sub>, finish.
> 2. Gather the set of producible media types *P*:
>
>    - If the method is annotated with `@Produces`, set *P* = {*V*(method)} where *V* (`t`) represents the values of `@Produces` on the specified target `t`.
>    - Else if the class is annotated with `@Produces`, set *P* = {V (class)}.
>    - Else set *P* = {*V* (writers)} where '`writers`' is the set of `MessageBodyWriter` that support the class of the returned entity object.
> 3. If *P* = {}, set *P* = {`'*/*'`}
> 4. Obtain the acceptable media types *A*. If *A* = {}, set *A* = {`'*/*'`}
> 5. Set *M* = {}. For each member of *A*; `a`:
>
>    - For each member of *P*; `p`:
>
>      1. If a is compatible with `p`, add *S*(`a`; `p`) to *M*, where the function `S` returns the most specific media type of the pair with the q-value of `a` and server-side qs-value of `p`.
> 6. If *M* = {} then generate a `NotAcceptableException` (406 status) and no entity. The exception MUST be processed as described in Section 3.3.4. Finish.
> 7. Sort *M* in descending order, with a primary key of specificity `(n/m > n/* > */*)`, a secondary key of q-value and a tertiary key of qs-value.
> 8. For each member of *M*; `m`:
>
>    - If `m` is a concrete type, set *M*<sub>selected</sub> = `m`, finish.
> 9. If *M* contains `'*/*'` or `'application/*`', set *M*<sub>selected</sub> = `'application/octet-stream'`, finish.
> 10. Generate a `NotAcceptableException` (406 status) and no entity. The exception MUST be processed as described in Section 3.3.4. Finish.

You can see it's not as easy as saying it will always default to `application/octet-stream`. Simple example

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Response createCustomer(@FormParam("id") int id, 
                               @FormParam("name") String name) {
    return Response.ok("OK I GOT IT").build();
}
```

The above will return `Content-Type: text/plain`

Say you create a `Customer` object and return it

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Response createCustomer(@FormParam("id") int id, 
                               @FormParam("name") String name) {
    Customer customer = new Customer(id, name);
    return Response.ok(customer).build();
}
```

From what I have tested, it will return `Content-Type: application/xml` and yes the body content *will* be xml.

Now if we send the request with an `Accept` header of `application/json`, we will get a response header of `Content-Type: application/json`, as yes the body content will be json. This is where Content Negotiation plays a factor

If we just responded with a `201 Created`, which is very common in `POST`/create requests

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Response createCustomer(@FormParam("id") int id, 
                               @FormParam("name") String name) {
    return Response.created(someNewUri).build();
}
```

there will be *no* `Content-Type` response header, as there's no content.

Now some of the example above aren't great REST princial examples, but it goes to show, that a lot goes in to determining the media type, if we don't explicitly set it with `@Produces`. You have to consider, the body of the response, available `MessageBodyWriters`, you have [**Content Negotiation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation) to factor in, and whatever else is in that mumbo-jumbo from the spec. (Note: I've bolded the'Content Negotiation' link because it is a concept you should really get familiar with when working with REST. It actually plays a big part with JAX-RS/Jersey).

So really the answer to your question is **it depends**. But hopefully you've gained some extra knowledge from this post :-)