# Is it good practice to use @Produces("application/json") on all JSON producing endpoints?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

We started using Jersey/JAX-RS for internal REST endpoints that get used by our front-end code. Endpoints that have to return a result, always send JSON objects.

For debugging purposes, we are using the firefox [restclient](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/restclient/) extension. Until recently, I would just enter the URL and hit send, and would get back content displayed as JSON.

But when I did that this morning, the FF extension comes back and tells me that I have to change the response type to binary (BLOB). Doing so results in displaying an encoded string instead of JSON.

I could resolve that by setting a request header (`Accept:` to be `application/json`).

Doing some more research, I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27544242/what-does-jersey-service-return-if-produces-annotation-missing). My *conclusion* is: probably we should add `@Produces("application/json")` to all these endpoints.

Question: is it really that simple, or are there good technical reasons to *not* do that?

Comment: you may be interested in that question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594945/how-correctly-produce-json-by-restful-web-service#13595212

Comment: I don't see why an endpoint that always produces json should not be annotated this way, especially if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should *always* declare the `@Produces` and `@Consumes` annotations (either at the class level or method level) for the purpose of [Content Negotiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation) and HTTP protocol correctness. Without these annotations, the result will be dependent on the client request and the default behavior of the server (which may be different across implementations), which leads to unpredictable and ambiguous results.

With these annotations, we *advertise* what media types we can produce and consume. On Retrieve (GET) requests, the client should send an `Accept` header with the media type of the resource they expect back. And on Create requests (PUT, POST), the client should send a `Content-Type` header telling the server what media type the data is that they are sending. If these headers don't match what the server is advertised to handle, then the client will get error responses back telling them what the problem is; with a Retrieve request and a non-matching `Accept` header, the response will be a [406 Not Acceptable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/406). With a Create request and a non-matching `Content-Type` header, the response will be a [415 Unsupported Media Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415).

This is how content negotiation works. And to make sure our server behaves as the clients expect, we should declare what we can handle on the server. The annotations do just this.

As you mentioned, when you left off the `@Produces`, the client told you you needed to change the response type. This is because the result was that the `Content-Type` response header was set to `application/octet-stream`, which is what [the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27544242/2587435) conclude. Clients use the `Content-Type` header to determine how to handle the response.

That last example was for a Retrieve request. If we left off the `@Consumes` on a Create endpoint, a lot of different things can go wrong. Take for example we have an endpoint that we want to accept JSON, so we create a POJO to map the JSON to.

```
@POST
public Response create(Customer customer) {}
```

For this to work, it is dependent on the client setting the `Content-Type` header on the request to `application/json`.  But without the `@Consumes` annotation, we are basically advertising this endpoint to be able to accept *any* media type, which is just ridiculous. The `@Consumes` annotation acts like a guard saying "If you don't send the right type of data, you cannot pass". But since we don't have the guard, all data is allowed through, and the result is unpredictable, because depending on what the client sets the `Content-Type` to, we don't know what `MessageBodyReader`<sup>1</sup> will handle the conversion from the entity body to `Customer`. If the correct `MessageBodyReader` is not chosen (the one that converts JSON to POPJOs), then most likely it will lead to an exception, and the client will get back a 500 Internal Server Error, which is not as specific as getting a 415 Unsupported Media Type.

---

<sub>1. [See chapter 8 and 9 of the Jersey docs](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/index.html). It will explain how entity bodies are converted to Java objects (and vice versa) using `MessageBodyReader` and `MessageBodyWriter`, respectively.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

> Is it good practice to use `@Produces("application/json")` on all JSON producing endpoints?

If your resource methods produce JSON as representation of your resources, they *should* be annotated with `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`. As a result, the response will have a [`Content-Type`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5) header indicating the media type of the payload.

The [`@Produces`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Produces.html) annotation is also used for *request matching*:  The JAX-RS runtime matches the media type sent in the [`Accept`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.2) header with the media type defined in the [`@Produces`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Produces.html) annotation.

---

If you don't want to annotate every resource method in your application, you can annotate the resource classes instead. It will indicate that all methods defined in such class must produce JSON as representation of your resources.

---

The media type defined in the [`@Produces`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Produces.html) annotation indicates the media type that will be produced by the [`MessageBodyWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html) instances registered in the application. Consider the following example:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Foo getFoo() {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    return Response.ok(foo).build();
}
```

Once the `getFoo()` method is annotated with `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`, JAX-RS will write the `Foo` instance as a JSON document. It's done in a [`MessageBodyWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html) implementation. If your application uses [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), for example, the [`JacksonJsonProvider`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-jaxrs-providers/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/json/JacksonJsonProvider.html) will be used to convert Java objects to JSON documents.

Comment: I assume: annotating the class would only effect methods that *return* values? (sorry, I am really a noob here).

Comment: @GhostCat Yes. And you use `@Consumes` to indicate the media type consumed by your API.