# Is it possible to send two different Content-Type for downloading file using jax-rs POST method

Tags: java, post, jersey, jax-rs

Is it possible to send two different Content-Type for POST method using post-man? Like, if the service is used for downloading excel file so in that case, `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` is used for sending some user detail which is json structure and `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)` is used for sending back the response as file.
NOTE: I don't want to use form-data, that is a constraint for this service.

Comment: You can map same URL to GET,POST,DELETE ...etc

Comment: In one call i am trying to consume json and get response as file.

Comment: Create a POST method. `return Response
                .ok(fileStream, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                .header("content-disposition","attachment; filename = myfile.xls")
                .build();`

Comment: @SumeshTG when i am calling the POST method from postman i get response as ��ࡱ�. Does file download feature can't be called from postman ?

Comment: Send and download feature of postman can be used for this purpose.

Comment: Ya Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the client request, the [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header is only for the type of data that is in the entity body. The [`Accept`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) header is what you send for the type of data you want back.

On the server side, it is perfectly fine to do the following.

```
@POST
@Path("something")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response post(Model model) throws Exception {
    final InputStream in = new FileInputStream("path-to-file");
    StreamingOutput entity = new StreamingOutput() {
        @Override
        public void write(OutputStream out) {
            IOUtils.copy(in, out);
            out.flush();
        }
    };
    return Response.ok(entity)
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
                    "attachment;filename=somefile.xls")
            .build();
}
```

The request to this endpoint should look like

```
POST /api/something HTTP 1.1
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Accept: application/octet-stream

{"the":"json", "entity":"body"}
```

**See also:**

- [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51182697/2587435) about purpose of `@Produces` and `@Consumes` and the role they play in content negotiation.

---

#### Aside

As an aside, consider using `application/vnd.ms-excel` as the `Content-Type` instead of `application/octet-stream`. This is already the standard MIME type for Microsoft Excel files<sup>1</sup>.  When using `StreamingOutput` as the response entity type, you can make the `@Produces` anything you want, as there is no real conversion needed.

In Postman, when you use the "Send and download" feature, you will notice that when the `Content-Type` is `application/octet-stream`, it will suggest the file extension of `.bin` when saving the file. But if you have the `Content-Type` as `application/vnd.ms-excel`, then the suggested extension is `.xls`, which is what it should be.

---

<sub>1. [Incomplete list of MIME types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types)</sub>

Comment: When i am calling this POST method using postman i get output as : ��ࡱ� in-spite of the pop-up for file download.

Comment: Well yeah, it's a binary file. You're not going to get plain text. Did you try to open it in a program that understands the excel format?